# Angular Material FAB doesn't close in an mdDialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have an issue with  FAB that seems to initialize open and I can't close it.  The menu items also seem to be consuiming space on the line rather than floating over it.

Not sure what I did 'wrong'.

http://codepen.io/ed4becky/pen/eJwYvw

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Testing FAB in Dialog">
  <md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <h2>Testing FAB in Dialog</h2>
      <span flex></span>
      <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="cancel()">
        <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_close_24px.svg" aria-label="Close dialog"></md-icon>
      </md-button>
    </div>
  </md-toolbar>
  <md-dialog-content style="max-width:800px;max-height:810px; ">
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
      <md-tab label="one">
        <md-content class="md-padding" style="width:600px;">
          <md-fab-speed-dial md-direction="left" ng-class="md-fling" ng-cloak>
            <md-fab-trigger>
              <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-warn md-mini">
                X
              </md-button>
            </md-fab-trigger>
            <md-fab-actions>
              <md-button aria-label="no" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini md-warn">
                No
              </md-button>
              <md-button aria-label="yes" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini md-accent">
                Yes
              </md-button>
            </md-fab-actions>
          </md-fab-speed-dial>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
  </md-dialog-content>

  <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
    <md-button ng-click="cancel()" style="margin-right:20px;">
      Done
    </md-button>
  </md-dialog-actions>
</md-dialog>
```

Comment: I know it's a bit late, are you still looking for an answer to this issue?

Comment: I worked around it.  Might have bene by updating the newer version, not sure.

Comment: Hi @ed4becky, did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

> Here you have a [working plunker](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBVaYR)

Just a few things to keep in mind:

1. As you post in a comment, update to an up to date `angular-material` version. Plunker is using the latest `1.1.1` relase
2. `ng-class` accepts an expression as parameter, so you should change `ng-class="md-fling"` per `ng-class="'md-fling'"` if you don't bind the value to a controller variable.
3. When you call the `$mdDialog.show(...)` service, you are setting `parent: angular.element(document.body)`. Not sure if you really need this for your use case, but if you remove it, it works well.

Code, just for reference:

**View:**

```
...
<md-fab-speed-dial md-direction="left" ng-class="'md-fling'" ng-cloak>
    <md-fab-trigger>
      <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-warn md-mini">
        X
      </md-button>
    </md-fab-trigger>
    <md-fab-actions>
      <md-button aria-label="no" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini md-warn">
        No
      </md-button>
      <md-button aria-label="yes" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini md-accent">
        Yes
      </md-button>
    </md-fab-actions>
</md-fab-speed-dial>
...
```

**Controller:**

```
...
$scope.showTabDialog = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      templateUrl: 'tabDialog.tmpl.html',
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose:true
    });
};
...
```

Hope it helps